# Finding the Riemann stieltjes integral using partitions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Please take a look at the following example :

$α(x)=x$ when $0≤x≤1$

$α(x)=x+2$ when $1< x≤2$

Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2}xdα(x)$

I solved this using the integration by parts formula and got the answer as 4. But what I am curious to know is how to solve this using partitions. Say I take a partition as follows;

P={$0,1/n,2/n,...,1,(n+1)/n,(n+2)/n,...,2$}.

I want to know the best way to proceed forward. Is it by using Riemann sums and take the limit or use upper sums and lower sums? If I choose to go with Riemann sums can i take the choice point as $i/n$ where $i=1,...,2n$ and calculate a limit? or should it be a arbitrary point within $[i-1/n,i/n]$? Do we always have to use arbitrary point or depending on the functions can we make that choice? I hope my question is not confusing. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Take your partitions of $\alpha$, not of $x$.

Comment: @Arkamis I don't understand. what do you mean partitions of α?

Comment: I mean, you do it exactly the same as you would for ordinary Riemann integration, but you write your upper (resp. lower) sums as $\sum M_i\Delta \alpha_i$ (resp. $\sum m_i \Delta \alpha_i$) where $\Delta \alpha_i = \alpha(x_i)-\alpha(x_{i-1})$. Basically everything is the same, and if you meet integrability, then it is true that for $s_i, t_i \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$, that $\sum |f(s_i)-f(t_i)|\Delta \alpha_i < \epsilon$, for some $\epsilon$ that makes sense for your refinement.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it by using Riemann sums and take the limit or use upper sums and lower sums?

Upper and lower sums are preferable: fewer choices to make.

> If I choose to go with Riemann sums can i take the choice point as $i/n$ where $i=1,...,2n$ and calculate a limit? or should it be a arbitrary point within $[i−1/n,i/n]$?

Depends. Do you already know (from some theorem) that the integral exists? If yes, you can take a convenient point such as $i/n$, because the limit of Riemann sums is already known to be independent of your choice. If not,  you must consider arbitrary points.

> Do we always have to use arbitrary point or depending on the functions can we make that choice?

Usually, neither: there are better ways to evaluate integrals than looking at partitions.  Also the answer depends on whether we know if the integral exists: see above.